# Where vs Having - Why do I get different results when setting date conditions? (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause, having

I am trying to understand how MySql processes a date condition differently when I set it on the 'WHERE' part of the code vs the 'HAVING' part. Can you please help me understand what is the difference in the logic in the below cases? How come I get just one product when I apply the date condition using HAVING, but I get two if I use the WHERE?

Question: Write an SQL query that reports the products that were only sold in spring 2019. That is, between 2019-01-01 and 2019-03-31 inclusive.

```
+------------+--------------+------------+
| product_id | product_name | unit_price |
+------------+--------------+------------+
| 1          | S8           | 1000       |
| 2          | G4           | 800        |
| 3          | iPhone       | 1400       |
+------------+--------------+------------+

Sales table:
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
| seller_id | product_id | buyer_id | sale_date  | quantity | price |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
| 1         | 1          | 1        | 2019-01-21 | 2        | 2000  |
| 1         | 2          | 2        | 2019-02-17 | 1        | 800   |
| 2         | 2          | 3        | 2019-06-02 | 1        | 800   |
| 3         | 3          | 4        | 2019-05-13 | 2        | 2800  |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
```

1. HAVING OPTION (the correct one)

   ```
   FROM Sales s 
   JOIN Product p 
   ON s.product_id = p.product_id
   GROUP by s.product_id
   HAVING min(sale_date)>='2019-01-01' AND max(sale_date)<='2019-03-31'
   ```
2. HAVING RESULT
   {"headers": ["product_id", "product_name"], "values": [[1, "S8"]]}
3. WHERE OPTION

   ```
   FROM Sales s 
   JOIN Product p 
   ON s.product_id = p.product_id
   WHERE sale_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-03-31'
   GROUP by s.product_id
   ```
4. WHERE RESULT
   {"headers": ["product_id", "product_name"], "values": [[1, "S8"], **[2, "G4"]**]}

Where does that 2, G4 come from?
(Apologies in advance if this is trivial, I am genuinely trying to learn on my own and I don't have anyone to ask)

Comment: The WHERE clause is evaluated before the aggregation (GROUP BY), HAVING is for set function conditions.

Comment: I.e. Your WHERE query will return any product sold at least during the period., While the HAVING will return products only sold during the period,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` is filtering the rows to only consider sales in Jan, Feb, and March.  So, any product that has sales in that period are included.

On the other hand, the `HAVING` is considering *all* sales for a product. Then for each product it is looking at the minimum and maximum dates.  Only products that have *all* sales in Jan, Feb, and March are included.

Consider `product_id = 2`.  It has a sale in February, so it would be included by the `WHERE` clause.  However, it also has a sale in June.  So the maximum date is Jun -- and the `HAVING` clause filters it out.